# Get value from cell containing array formula

Tags: java, selenium, apache-poi, xssf

I have XSSFWorkbook and I've put **array formulas** in two column and I want to copy the values from these columns and paste onto other columns.

Formula looks like this:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$C$13,MATCH(1,(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$13=$A2)*(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$13=$D2),0),2),"FAIL")}
```

I have placed the formula (by running a loop on multiple cells) like this (sheet is XSSFSheet):

```
String formula = "AboveFormulaWithIterativeCell"  // (without {} and =)
String range = "XFC" + i;  // i is iterative row number
sheet.setArrayFormula(formula, CellRangeAddress.valueOf(range));
```

And then evaluated the formulas like this (wb is XSSFWorkbook):

```
XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(wb);
```

Everything is working fine till this point. Formulas are displaying valid result.

Now if I run a loop on these cells and read the value like this (c is Cell):

```
String cellValue = c.getStringCellValue();
```

It always returning "FAIL", like it is returning the result after evaluating the formula as non-array formula.

So I've tried same thing with this formula:

```
{=IF(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE)}
```

And surprisingly it is returning me TRUE.

**So, my question is how this formula is returning correct result and not my main formula.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Apache Poi is still not supporting the manipulating table formulas (Array formulas).

> Not yet supported   Manipulating table formulas (In Excel, formulas
>   that look like "{=...}" as opposed to "=...")

See [**here**](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/formula.html) for more details.

So I had to convert my array formula to non-array formula.

**Note:**
You can still use array formulas, if you just want to display the result.
But you can not get the value from cell which contains array formula.